# How to create Edit button in form

Tags: axapta, x++

I created a normal form with an edit button, the fields of the table have the Allow Edit property set to "no". Now the edit button is not working. If I change the Allow Edit property of fields to YES that time it will work.

Answer (score 2):

By setting `AllowEdit = No` on the form data source, you are disabling the ability to edit completely.

The `Edit` button on the forms essentially toggle between `view` and `edit` mode. The data source needs to have `AllowEdit = Yes` in order for any edits to be performed.

When a user opens a form in `View` mode, they still have the ability to edit the data, but it's a feature to prevent accidental edits.